Music.app Select Songs Listing via Applescript
I would like to Select the "Songs" library view (in the left-hand pane) via Applescript, but all I can do is select the Album view by doing the following:
  tell application "Music"
    activate
    set view of front window to playlist ("Music")
  end tell

Selecting playlist "Songs" gets an error.
 Can’t set view of window 1 to playlist \"Songs\"." number -10006 from view of window 1

Playlist "Library" doesn't work either.
Any idea what's going on?

There is a hierarchy to all the stuff in Music/iTunes. At the top is the source, and below that are the playlists, the main one of which is the library playlist. From the Script Editor, select File > Open Dictionary… and find the Music one and open it. Information about the various applescript commands is in there. I still use itunes so I don't know if things have changed but I don't see much in the way of setting the 'view'.
